# Why does this C struct code work?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am toying with pointers to structures and array of structures to see how they work. I am confounded why this following piece of work compiles and produces the right result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    typedef struct {
        char *name;
        int count;
    } word;
word *word_array;
word_array = malloc(sizeof(word));
word_array[2048].name = "foo";
word_array[2048].count = 5;
printf("%s %d\n", word_array[2048].name, word_array[2048].count);
```

This prints: foo 5

How much memory does the malloc allocate to word_array? What's even going on? Is this undefined behaviour that just happens to compile and run?

Comment: It is undefined behavior indeed.

Comment: The thing is, assignments to word_array[10].name, word_array[5].count, they ALL work...

Comment: No, they don't! See, *undefined* means **undefined**.

Comment: The C specification defines this to be undefined behaviour. In reality, you're happening to write the data to a page which has actually been allocated, so it doesn't crash, but it's still undefined and you *must* not rely on it. It may crash, it may crash ten minutes in the future, it may work fine, it may format your hard drive.

Comment: What @iharob means is that, they work now, but they may not work in the future.  It's undefined behavior.

Comment: Hmm. So this would be right if i do word_array = malloc(2048*sizeof(word))?

Comment: No, it would be right `if (word_array != NULL)` after `malloc()`.

Comment: @nirvanaswap That would alllocate memory for 2048 words, but you'd be accessing the 2049th.

Comment: @iharob I'm not quite sure what you mean. Can you elaborate? :)

Comment: @nirvanaswap `malloc()` returns `NULL` on error. You should always check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How much memory does the malloc allocate to word_array?

`sizeof(word)` bytes, just like you told it to - so enough memory to hold one `word`.

> What's even going on? Is this undefined behaviour that just happens to compile and run?

Yes. Note that it's not surprising that it compiles (most undefined behaviour does not cause a compilation error, or even a warning).

Since you already seem to know about undefined behaviour, you know that it might crash, or it might seem to work, or anything in-between. Maybe next Tuesday your program will crash when you try to show it to the CEO. Maybe you'll upgrade your compiler in six months and then it'll start crashing consistently. If your program writes any files, *then maybe it's already corrupting those files*. And so on.